# Mathematical subjects in Japanese

Tags: mathematics

I have troubles finding the following expressions or the like in Japanese. It is in mathematical contexts:

1. Differential geometry
2. (Point-set) Topology
3. Submanifolds
4. Smooth functions

Are there places where I can find similar terms more directly? I know that jisho.org does cover some basic terms (yes, you can find stuff like Riemann curvature tensor) but sometimes I cannot find basic ones (like I can find geometry and manifold but not differential geometry).

Comment: Wikipedia's other languages feature is very useful for this purpose: For example Differential geometry links to https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BE%AE%E5%88%86%E5%B9%BE%E4%BD%95%E5%AD%A6

Comment: Another good free online resource is Eijiro.  See [their entry for "differential geometry"](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=differential%20geometry), for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don Zagier has a [4-page scan](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/EnglishJapaneseDictMathTerm/fulltext.pdf) of an *English–Japanese Dictionary for Mathematical Terminology*. Being only 4 pages short, it is only a "cheat sheet" and maybe serves less as a dictionary and more as a first vocabulary list of expressions to learn. (Japanese mathematics libraries will have dictionaries with hundreds of pages for this purpose.)

ALC's 英辞郎 which @Eiríkr Útlendi suggested in the comments seems to be quite complete as it contains even more technical terminology (such as *derived functor*, *plurisubharmonic function*, *properly discontinuous action*, etc.). Else, @Ringil's strategy of finding the term on Wikipedia and looking on the linked Japanese site is also a good strategy.

The terms you're asking about would be

1. 微分幾何学【びぶんきかがく】 differential geometry
2. 位相幾何学【いそうきかがく】 topology (the subject area)
3. 部分多様体【ぶぶんたようたい】 submanifold/subvariety
4. 滑らか【なめらか】な関数【かんすう】 smooth function